# Retrieving page with fsockopen adds numbers to returned string

Tags: php, sockets, stream, fsockopen

This is very strange, on some pages it will return the HTML fine, others it will add numbers to the beginning and end of the returned string (`$out`).

```
function lookupPage($page, $return = true) {
    $fp = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 48580, $errno, $errstr, 5);        
    if (!$fp) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $out = "";
        $headers = "GET /" . $page . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $headers .= "Host: www.site.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $headers);
        stream_set_timeout($fp, 300);
        $info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
        while (!feof($fp) && !$info['timed_out'] && ($line = stream_get_line($fp, 1024)) !== false) {
            $info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
            if ($return) $out .= $line;
        }
        fclose($fp);
        if (!$info['timed_out']) {
            if ($return) {
                $out = substr($out, strpos($out, "\r\n\r\n") + 4);
                return $out;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

e.g...

```
3565
<html>
<head>
...
</html>
0
```

Comment: I've come across this before and racking my brain. I think it was something to do with HTTP compression or something added in to the HTTP 1.1 protocol.

I'm trying to google to confirm exactly but not finding anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [Chunked Transfer Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

It is part of the HTTP 1.1 protocol and you're decoding it in a HTTP 1.0 way. You can just check for the values and trim them if you want. They only show the length of the response so the browser knows it has the complete response.

Also maybe look at  [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

Comment: Yes your right, the headers that come back say "Transfer-Encoding: chunked". Is there an easy way to decode this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the server responds with chunked data.

Have a look at [RFC2616 Transfer codings](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6) and its [introduction](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.4.6).